# jQuery ajax issue, stacking divs

Tags: jquery, ajax, load

I have a little code for dynamically loading part of my web:

```
$('a#ajax-call').click(function (e) {
    $("#container").load('/process.php',{id:myID},function(data){
        return;
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

which returns this html scheme:

```
<div>my ajax loaded content</div>
```

and appends to this scheme:

```
<div id=container>
     <div>php loaded content 1</div>
     <div>php loaded content 2</div>
     <div id="static">php loaded content static</div>
     <div>php loaded content 3</div>
     ... until 12 divs...
</div>
```

the problem is, load is replacing whole content of `#container` and I need show this way:

```
<div id=container>
     <div>ajax loaded content </div>
     <div>php loaded content 1</div>
     <div id="static">php loaded content static</div> <--- remains static
     <div>php loaded content 2</div>
     ... until 12 divs...
 </div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: So are you just adding they first div or did you forget to change the others in the updated result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('a#ajax-call').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
    url: '/process.php',
    type: "POST",
    data: "id="+myID,
    cache: true,
    success: function(data){
    $("#container").append(data);           
    }
    });
});
```

and modify your anchor tag as

```
<a href="javascript:;" id="ajax-call"> ... </a>
```

if you are not using e.preventDefault(); function in ajax call

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like:

```
$.get('/process.php', {id: myID}, function(data) {

    $("#container").append(data);
    return;
});
```

According to jQuery's documentation about `$.load()`:

> When a successful response is detected (i.e. when textStatus is "success" or "notmodified"), .load() sets the HTML contents of the matched element to the returned data.

Comment: $("#container").append(data); is going to append at the end, probably you should use prepend http://api.jquery.com/prepend/